# exe file not found after gcc creates output

Tags: c, gcc, exe

Hello I am learning c and I have created a simple script. I ran it with `gcc simplify.c -o simplify`.

Here is the c script

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int age = 3;
    printf("%i\n", age);

    return 0;

}
```

when I try to run it

```
$simplify.exe
bash: run: command not found
```

I get the result shown. What am I doing wrong

Comment: Usually the current directory `.` is not part of the `PATH` where the shell looks for executable programs ([for very good reasons](https://superuser.com/questions/156582/why-is-not-in-the-path-by-default)). You need to use e.g. `./simplify.exe` to run the program in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use a filename as a command, bash will search for it in directorys like `/usr/bin`. Imagine the situation, in which someone put a executable called `ls` somewhere unprotected on your computer. Like @some programmer dude pointed out, you habe to explicitly specify the path to your executable. This path can be relative (./simplify.exe) or absolute (/home/username/projects/simplify/simplify.exe).

By the way, on linux systems it is umcommon to use a file ending, espacially ".exe". If you want to use one, I recommend ".elf", which stands for "executable linkable file". (You can do so much more than EXEcuting a file - and down we go the rabbit hole)